# How to automate versioning app on a successful merge in GitLab CI?

Tags: node.js, devops, gitlab-ci, jobs

I am new to app deployment, basically I want to automate the process of incrementing the version of my app whenever a merge request is approved.

- So a merge request is sent to the test branch
- tests run
- user manually completes the merge request into test branch via button click

** Here I want to automate running npm version patch and update the packages & package version on the test branch **

Any ideas on how I can implement this successfully? I have been researching and also already tried having this run in a separate job that runs only on the test branch, but then it was failing because it runs in an infinite loop - it will update the version, then GitLab rebuilds it, then it runs update again since the jobs are sequential.

Ex of what I tried so far:

```
update-v:
  stage: update
  script:
    - echo "moving on to update build version..."
    - npm version patch
  only:
    - test
```

Comment: If you're pushing from the job to GitLab, it supports git push -o ci.skip to prevent loops, would it solve your problem?